# React update view when api's loading variable is false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a fetch function like follow which I found on the net and seems like a great way to retrieve api information:

```
const useFetch = (url, options = defaultOptions) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const res = await fetch(url, options);
      const json = await res.json();
      setResponse(json);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
    }
  }, [options, url]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (url) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [url]);

  return {
    error,
    fetchData,
    loading,
    response,
  };
};
```

Now I try to retrieve the data in another component and update the view whenever the loading variable is updated.

Like so:

```
const Test = () => {
  const { loading, response } = useFunctionThatExtendsUseFetch();

  const template = () => {
    if (loading) {
      console.log('loading', loading);
      return 'loading';
    }

    console.log('finished loading', response);
    return response;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{content}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But nothing budges, not sure why... The loading variable does change though when I console log it's value in the component.

Thank you

Comment: what is useFunctionThatExtendsUseFetch()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, `content` is not defined and `template` is never used. Try this:

```
const Test = () => {
  const { loading, response } = useFunctionThatExtendsUseFetch();

  if (loading) {
    console.log('loading', loading);
  } else {
    console.log('finished loading', response);
  }

  const content = loading ? 'loading' : response;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{content}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or you could simply replace `{content}` with `{template()}` in your code.

But if your response isn't a string, you'll have issues.

Comment: It happens to all of us... all the time.